# How can I remove the latency from my USB QWERTY keyboard to play piano with it in real time?

Tags: usb, keyboard, latency, keystrokes

I'd like to use my USB QWERTY keyboard to play piano with various MIDI apps and websites.

For anyone who has tried this, the problem is that keystrokes from the keyboard aren't send to the computer immediately. There is a little bit of latency each time a button is pressed. This makes playing piano with it impossible in terms of trying to play in rhythm of a beat.

**Is there a way to remove or reduce the latency and buffer between the keyboard and the computer?**

*Note: I'm not trying to use the keyboard as a MIDI input*

Comment: Most keyboard delays are in the millisecond range. What kind of keyboard are you using? What kind of delay are you getting?

Comment: @HazardousGlitch - the keyboard is unlikely to be the issue, see my lengthier comment on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to remove or reduce the latency and buffer between the keyboard and the computer?

No, most probably there is no way for that.

That latency is not intentional, it's the time necessary to process the information, send it to the computer and the computer to process it again.

You might find more expensive keyboards with lower latency, also wired devices can be better for your purpose.

> the problem is that keystrokes from the keyboard aren't send to the computer immediately

That's one problem, another one (for me the biggest) is that keyboards only sense whether a button is pressed or not, neither the speed, neither the force of pressing can be captured (it's by design).

Even if you could completely get rid of the latency, you couldn't get an experience even close to a piano.

Comment: If USB travels at the speed of light, then why is the information not sent as quickly? Why are people able to plug in a midi controller or sound input to a computer and have that information transferred without latency, when a USB input has latency?

Comment: You are conflating information. Each bit travels at the speed of light, but it depends how long behind it the next bit is transmitted. However, that's only half the problem... your MIDI software then needs time to capture that input, translate it to a form it can use & send that to your piano sample, then play that sample out to you - that's what takes the time. You can shorten that by reducing your DAW's buffers [until breakup starts to occur, then back it off one increment.] Also, using ASIO rather than Windows' own MME as your MIDI 'translator' would be faster.

Comment: Ty Tetsujin, this is helpful but not entirely. When I use autohotkey to press the keyboard inputs there is less delay for the audio to play. As a result, most of the delay is coming from the USB keyboard itself and not from the sound card. I just don't understand why a USB keyboard would have such a long delay like that. How can a synth piano have no delay when that's operating under an OS, but a USB keyboard has to have a delay? I see no reason for this.

Comment: Then it must be how the keyboard is being prioritised. For that, I have no idea, it's simply not something I've ever tried. I just use an actual piano keyboard & input over midi>USB.